# Figure or longtabu/longtable causes bottom margin overflow

Tags: margins, longtable

I have been searching for a while now without any luck, so I hope you can help me. The problem is that when I insert a figure/longtabu on my page, the text below is running out of the page, like this image shows:

[image]

Do you know what the problem is here?

I have uploaded some sample code here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5460d3e57c82cd0747da476d

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum and include it to your post. Are you sure, it has something to do with some figure? I would say, the `longtabu` is preventing a page break here. Just guessing; I won't debug 97 lines for you.

Comment: My guess is the same as @LaRiFaRi, plus you are doing a lot of things wrong in that document. And additionally you are aware that the file does not even compile?

Comment: Sorry for that. I must have been disturbed with something. I will fix it now.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I have reduced the code sample now and hope that you will have a second look at it.

Comment: @daleif I have reduced the code sample now and hope that you will have a second look at it.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I am not sure it is the figure anymore. I only know that it is somewhere in the content left on the page. Most of the text is auto generated with lipsum for the test case.

Comment: @FireFly3000, I've added a simpler example below, added the `longtable` tag and added `longtable` to the title. Remember when you use `\raggedleft` and similar in the last column of a table, then you need to use `\raggedleft\arraybackslash`. I do not know if `tabu` automatically added that. Also note that it seems that the `tabu` author has abandoned the project.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue over here, too. This worked for me

http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512

Apparently longtable had some issues on calculating the size of the page when a float is on the same page. I modified my longtable.sty file according to the instructions and now all is splendid, once again! :D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is that patch still needed?

Comment: @MartinSchröder for me (TexLive 2016 distro on Mac) - yes. I had to apply this patch (tried `tlmgr update longtable` before). Also bug status says it is still open since `Arrival date: Sun Mar 09 21:41:00 +0100 2003`. Seriously???

Comment: Please, tell me how to apply this patch. My latex installation does not have the /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools folder

Comment: On a Linux system, `kpsewhich longtable.sty` in the shell will tell you where it is located.

Comment: @david-carlisle I still encounter this problem many years after being reported - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507535/caption-and-longtable-forcing-text-out-of-margin?noredirect=1#comment1282578_507535

Comment: This is currently an open bug at the LaTeX project: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/158

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what is going on here. But I've reduced it to the following

It seems to be longtable related. I'll retag the question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{ l }
  A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\
\end{longtable}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{KDBrugafDDGFW}
    \caption{sss}
    \label{fig:KDBrugafDDGFW}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtable}{ l }
  A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\
\end{longtable}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works OK with [v5](https://dpctex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/longtable/) presumably the fix from tools/3512 in the latex bug database....