# Longtable exceeds page length

Tags: floats, header-footer, longtable, fancyhdr, xtable

Situation:
I am using rmarkdown and xtable to iterate the creation of several tables, and output them in Latex to create a PDF.
Given that most tables are long, Im using Longtable package.
Also, i need to insert two aligned images on the top of each page. For this i use Fancyhdr and Graphicx to insert them in the header.

Complication:
The tables created exceed the page length. They brake and continue in the next page, but there are several rows below the page length, thus, are not shown in the pdf. Same with footer.
This wont happen if I dont insert the images. Without the images at the top of the pages, longtable works well.
Also, i noted that the second half of a splitted table (that is, the chunk of the table that longtable sends to the next page) starts lower in the page, compared to where the first table of the document starts.

Problem:
I cant get longtable to break the tables within the limits of the page length.

Code from rmarkdown (im showing the xtable code):

````
---
title: "Reportes generales"
output: 
  pdf_document:
header-includes:
- \geometry{layout=a4paper}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
- \usepackage[]{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,       
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    pdfstartview=Fit,           
    hyperindex=True
    hyperfigures=True
  }
- \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{insight-top-right-2.png}}
- \fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{2.3\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{logo.png}}}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


---
\listoftables

\newpage

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
datawrangling with r and calculations

### Here i am writing the code that will be inserted in the first line of the longtable, which states the use of endhead and endfoot, and footnotesize

addtorow<-list()
addtorow$pos<-list()
addtorow$pos[[1]]<-c(0)
addtorow$command<-c(paste("\\hline \n",
" \\endhead \n",
" \\hline \n",
" {\\footnotesize Continued on next page} \n",
" \\endfoot \n",
" \\endlastfoot \n",sep=""))

### Here is the tranformation of the dataframes to LaTex using xtable, note that tempmatrix is the matrix which i want to print in a pdf. This iterates for several dataframes, spawining several Longtables

xt <- capture.output(print.xtable(xtable(tempMatrix, align = "l|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|"), include.rownames = FALSE, comment = FALSE, floating = FALSE, tabular.environment = "longtable",add.to.row=addtorow))
cat(xt, sep="\n")
```
````

Finally, here is what the table in latex code looks like. This is one of several tables, only the information changes, format is the same for all:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
  \hline
DEPARTAMENTO & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
BEBE & 3,136,143 & 3,908,120 & 3,970,474 & 167,346,367 & 253,682,083 \\ 
  BELLEZA DE LA PIEL & 4,056,518 & 4,383,270 & 5,657,551 & 268,024,922 & 376,562,389 \\ 
  CUIDADO CAPILAR & 3,598,571 & 4,485,420 & 4,860,410 & 231,520,280 & 360,023,595 \\ 
  CUIDADO ORAL & 1,466,654 & 2,077,587 & 2,149,403 & 106,409,239 & 159,647,444 \\ 
  CUIDADO PERSONAL & 5,993,436 & 7,920,352 & 8,268,905 & 431,726,918 & 615,126,409 \\ 
  LIMPIEZA &   283,785 &   254,940 &   306,183 &  26,618,969 &  28,738,917 \\ 
  NO COMESTIBLES &        NA &        NA &        NA &  14,600,825 &  23,053,981 \\ 
  OTC &         0 &         0 &    24,176 &           0 &     108,372 \\ 
  PRIMEROS AUXILIOS &   546,344 &   857,384 &   924,860 &  36,689,415 &  53,886,336 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Possible solutions already tried and failed, by themself and in combination:

```
- \geometry{top=0cm}
- \geometry{bottom=5cm}
- \geometry{headsep=0pt}
- \geometry{includehead}
```

I really cant figure out how to solve this, and im getting desperate.

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I fount that longtable may have some issues calculating the size of the page when a float is on the same page, from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213911/figure-or-longtabu-longtable-causes-bottom-margin-overflow)
May that be the problem? maybe the images in the header messes up the way longtable calculates the page length. They propose a modification to longtable.sty, but i cant find it.

**UPDATE2:**  I could obtain the tex file rmarkdown uses to generate the pdf,as suggested here it is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim     environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={Reportes generales},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{Reportes generales}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
  \posttitle{\par}
  \author{}
  \preauthor{}\postauthor{}
  \date{}
  \predate{}\postdate{}

\geometry{layout=a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, pdfstartview=Fit, hyperindex=True hyperfigures=True }
\geometry{top=0.1cm}
\geometry{headsep=0pt}
\fancyhfoffset[L]{72pt}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{72pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{0.7\height}{\includegraphics[height=1.0cm]{logo.png}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{insight-top-right-3.png}}
\setlength{\LTpre}{1pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\listoftables

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
  \hline
DEPARTAMENTO & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
BEBE & 3,136,143 & 3,908,120 & 3,970,474 & 167,346,367 & 253,682,083 \\ 
  BELLEZA DE LA PIEL & 4,056,518 & 4,383,270 & 5,657,551 & 268,024,922 & 376,562,389 \\ 
  CUIDADO CAPILAR & 3,598,571 & 4,485,420 & 4,860,410 & 231,520,280 & 360,023,595 \\ 
  CUIDADO ORAL & 1,466,654 & 2,077,587 & 2,149,403 & 106,409,239 & 159,647,444 \\ 
  CUIDADO PERSONAL & 5,993,436 & 7,920,352 & 8,268,905 & 431,726,918 & 615,126,409 \\ 
  LIMPIEZA &   283,785 &   254,940 &   306,183 &  26,618,969 &  28,738,917 \\ 
  NO COMESTIBLES &        NA &        NA &        NA &  14,600,825 &  23,053,981 \\ 
  OTC &         0 &         0 &    24,176 &           0 &     108,372 \\ 
  PRIMEROS AUXILIOS &   546,344 &   857,384 &   924,860 &  36,689,415     &  53,886,336 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
  \hline
DEPARTAMENTO & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline
BEBE &  1.60 & 26.60 & 51.59 \\ 
  BELLEZA DE LA PIEL & 29.07 & 39.47 & 40.50 \\ 
  CUIDADO CAPILAR &  8.36 & 35.06 & 55.50 \\ 
  CUIDADO ORAL &  3.46 & 46.55 & 50.03 \\ 
  CUIDADO PERSONAL &  4.40 & 37.97 & 42.48 \\ 
  LIMPIEZA & 20.10 &  7.89 &  7.96 \\ 
  NO COMESTIBLES &    NA &    NA & 57.90 \\ 
  OTC &   Inf &   Inf &   Inf \\ 
  PRIMEROS AUXILIOS &  7.87 & 69.28 & 46.87 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  BELLEZA DE LA PIEL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
CREMAS FACIALES & 2,803,254 & 3,121,176 & 3,595,056 & 173,742,026 & 230,131,906 \\ 
  CREMAS P/CUERPO &   792,387 &   832,099 & 1,117,033 &  56,567,912 &  79,910,260 \\ 
  BRONCEADORES &   393,863 &   394,842 &   800,450 &  34,884,696 &  62,260,683 \\ 
  CREMAS REDUCTORAS &    67,014 &    35,153 &   145,012 &   2,830,287 &   4,259,539 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  BELLEZA DE LA PIEL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
CREMAS FACIALES &  15.18 &  28.25 & 32.46 \\ 
  CREMAS P/CUERPO &  34.24 &  40.97 & 41.26 \\ 
  BRONCEADORES & 102.73 & 103.23 & 78.48 \\ 
  CREMAS REDUCTORAS & 312.52 & 116.39 & 50.50 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  CUIDADO PERSONAL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
DESODORANTES CORPORALES & 2,063,564 & 2,735,511 & 2,720,461 & 154,726,728 & 213,362,316 \\ 
  TINTURAS & 1,011,545 & 1,309,711 & 1,441,668 &  61,215,451 & 103,688,813 \\ 
  JABONES DE TOCADOR &   857,958 & 1,132,913 & 1,145,764 &  67,971,560 &  96,365,051 \\ 
  PROTECCION SANITARIA FEMENINA &   996,205 & 1,428,784 & 1,465,860 &  68,427,382 &  92,990,493 \\ 
  HOJAS Y SISTEMAS DE AFEITAR &   463,789 &   577,544 &   684,020 &  36,823,238 &  49,877,736 \\ 
  DESODORANTES PEDICOS &   275,378 &   302,852 &   349,053 &  18,068,231 &  26,220,716 \\ 
  PRODUCTOS DEPILATORIOS &   169,226 &   200,146 &   225,431 &  12,888,939 &  17,012,924 \\ 
  CREMAS Y ESPUMAS DE AFEITAR &    65,707 &    81,179 &   101,928 &   5,363,923 &   7,065,802 \\ 
  JABONES DE TOCADOR INFANTIL &    41,112 &    76,530 &    60,340 &   2,996,544 &   4,375,777 \\ 
  PROTECTORES MAMARIOS &    25,921 &    36,486 &    37,044 &   1,582,267 &   2,538,494 \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES LIQUIDOS &    23,031 &    38,695 &    37,336 &   1,662,655 &   1,628,287 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  CUIDADO PERSONAL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
DESODORANTES CORPORALES &  \textcolor{red}{-0.55} & 31.83 & 37.90 \\ 
  TINTURAS &  10.08 & 42.52 & 69.38 \\ 
  JABONES DE TOCADOR &   1.13 & 33.55 & 41.77 \\ 
  PROTECCION SANITARIA FEMENINA &   2.59 & 47.14 & 35.90 \\ 
  HOJAS Y SISTEMAS DE AFEITAR &  18.44 & 47.49 & 35.45 \\ 
  DESODORANTES PEDICOS &  15.26 & 26.75 & 45.12 \\ 
  PRODUCTOS DEPILATORIOS &  12.63 & 33.21 & 32.00 \\ 
  CREMAS Y ESPUMAS DE AFEITAR &  25.56 & 55.13 & 31.73 \\ 
  JABONES DE TOCADOR INFANTIL & \textcolor{red}{-21.16} & 46.77 & 46.03 \\ 
  PROTECTORES MAMARIOS &   1.53 & 42.91 & 60.43 \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES LIQUIDOS &  \textcolor{red}{-3.51} & 62.11 & \textcolor{red}{-2.07} \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  BEBE} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PA-ALES DESCARTABLES P/BEBES & 2,122,630 & 2,780,865 & 3,079,733 & 113,368,516 & 188,264,578 \\ 
  TOALLAS HUMEDAS &   769,750 &   624,151 &   588,020 &  35,922,853 &  42,581,782 \\ 
  COLONIAS &   136,517 &   394,210 &   190,754 &  11,578,566 &  15,923,990 \\ 
  HISOPOS &    86,054 &    89,065 &    87,441 &   5,032,377 &   5,123,320 \\ 
  ACEITES INFANTILES &    21,191 &    19,603 &    22,353 &   1,439,380 &   1,749,265 \\ 
  ALIMENTOS PARA BEBE &         0 &       226 &     2,172 &       4,674 &      39,148 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  BEBE} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PA-ALES DESCARTABLES P/BEBES &  10.75 &  45.09 &  66.06 \\ 
  TOALLAS HUMEDAS &  \textcolor{red}{-5.79} & \textcolor{red}{-23.61} &  18.54 \\ 
  COLONIAS & \textcolor{red}{-51.61} &  39.73 &  37.53 \\ 
  HISOPOS &  \textcolor{red}{-1.82} &   1.61 &   1.81 \\ 
  ACEITES INFANTILES &  14.03 &   5.48 &  21.53 \\ 
  ALIMENTOS PARA BEBE & 861.38 &    Inf & 737.56 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  CUIDADO CAPILAR} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
SHAMPOO & 1,773,948 & 2,247,855 & 2,356,224 & 121,419,925 & 175,429,757 \\ 
  TRATAMIENTOS POST LAVADO CAPIL & 1,657,579 & 2,035,991 & 2,289,201 &  97,430,656 & 168,517,341 \\ 
  FIJADORES Y BRILLANTINAS &   167,044 &   201,573 &   214,985 &  12,669,698 &  16,076,497 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  CUIDADO CAPILAR} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
SHAMPOO &  4.82 & 32.82 & 44.48 \\ 
  TRATAMIENTOS POST LAVADO CAPIL & 12.44 & 38.11 & 72.96 \\ 
  FIJADORES Y BRILLANTINAS &  6.65 & 28.70 & 26.89 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  CUIDADO ORAL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
CREMAS DENTALES & 806,334 & 1,119,215 & 1,153,052 & 55,999,726 & 86,000,224 \\ 
  CEPILLOS DENTALES & 437,088 &   633,310 &   652,061 & 32,699,481 & 48,952,653 \\ 
  ENJUAGUE BUCAL & 196,601 &   286,640 &   307,849 & 15,756,802 & 21,779,345 \\ 
  HILOS DENTALES &  26,631 &    38,422 &    36,441 &  1,953,230 &  2,915,221 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  CUIDADO ORAL} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
CREMAS DENTALES &  3.02 & 43.00 & 53.57 \\ 
  CEPILLOS DENTALES &  2.96 & 49.18 & 49.70 \\ 
  ENJUAGUE BUCAL &  7.40 & 56.59 & 38.22 \\ 
  HILOS DENTALES & \textcolor{red}{-5.16} & 36.83 & 49.25 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  ALMACEN} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
LECHES MATERNIZADAS & 690,342 & 1,081,196 & 1,117,606 & 50,599,593 & 78,413,709 \\ 
  LECHES FLUIDAS INFANTILES & 305,284 &   406,650 &   356,478 & 17,418,316 & 32,561,526 \\ 
  EDULCORANTES &  81,847 &   108,511 &   108,040 &  5,062,420 &  8,405,514 \\ 
  LECHES EN POLVO ENTERAS Y DESC &  50,583 &    65,481 &    71,004 &  4,146,129 &  5,330,949 \\ 
  PASTILLAS &       0 &       200 &       150 &          0 &      9,000 \\ 
  POSTRES PREPARADOS &       0 &     5,398 &         0 &          0 &      5,398 \\ 
  AZUCAR &      NA &        NA &        NA &          0 &      1,546 \\ 
   \hline
    \hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  ALMACEN} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
LECHES MATERNIZADAS &    3.37 & 61.89 & 54.97 \\ 
  LECHES FLUIDAS INFANTILES &  \textcolor{red}{-12.34} & 16.77 & 86.94 \\ 
  EDULCORANTES &   \textcolor{red}{-0.43} & 32.00 & 66.04 \\ 
  LECHES EN POLVO ENTERAS Y DESC &    8.44 & 40.37 & 28.58 \\ 
  PASTILLAS &  \textcolor{red}{-25.00} &   Inf &   Inf \\ 
  POSTRES PREPARADOS & \textcolor{red}{-100}.00 &   NaN &   Inf \\ 
  AZUCAR &      NA &    NA &   Inf \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  PRIMEROS AUXILIOS} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PA-ALES DESCARTABLES P/ADULTO & 291,871 & 513,709 & 509,992 & 19,938,505 & 34,598,008 \\ 
  ALGODON & 109,650 & 128,338 & 129,161 &  7,944,323 &  9,423,255 \\ 
  PA-UELOS DESCARTABLES & 144,823 & 200,002 & 201,561 &  8,806,587 &  9,171,453 \\ 
  APOSITOS ADHESIVOS &       0 &  15,335 &  84,147 &          0 &    693,620 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  PRIMEROS AUXILIOS} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PA-ALES DESCARTABLES P/ADULTO &  \textcolor{red}{-0.72} & 74.73 & 73.52 \\ 
  ALGODON &   0.64 & 17.79 & 18.62 \\ 
  PA-UELOS DESCARTABLES &   0.78 & 39.18 &  4.14 \\ 
  APOSITOS ADHESIVOS & 448.73 &   Inf &   Inf \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  NO COMESTIBLES} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PERSONAL CARE & 202,776 & 342,134 & 283,591 & 12,525,189 & 19,873,598 \\ 
  PILAS Y BATERIAS &  26,811 &  51,955 &  34,284 &  2,073,855 &  3,170,379 \\ 
  LAMPARAS ELECTRICAS &      63 &      77 &     341 &      1,781 &     10,004 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  NO COMESTIBLES} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
PERSONAL CARE & \textcolor{red}{-17.11} &  39.85 &  58.67 \\ 
  PILAS Y BATERIAS & \textcolor{red}{-34.01} &  27.87 &  52.87 \\ 
  LAMPARAS ELECTRICAS & 342.86 & 443.43 & 461.72 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  LIMPIEZA} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
INSECTICIDAS TOTAL & 46,733 & 25,317 & 70,275 & 8,405,776 & 10,842,602 \\ 
  DESODORIZ. AMBIENTALES & 47,641 & 41,725 & 36,204 & 4,066,838 &  3,143,191 \\ 
  PAPEL HIGIENICO & 41,524 & 34,182 & 43,812 & 3,376,920 &  2,879,686 \\ 
  DETERGENTES LIQUIDOS & 16,513 & 19,675 & 19,315 & 1,252,239 &  1,586,210 \\ 
  ROLLOS DE PAPEL P/COCINA & 23,198 & 17,788 & 19,031 & 1,604,990 &  1,395,317 \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES EN POLVO & 14,511 & 16,699 & 16,702 &   961,115 &  1,284,704 \\ 
  DESOD.PARA INODOROS & 15,230 & 12,561 & 12,982 & 1,142,564 &  1,092,752 \\ 
  DILUIBLES & 11,072 & 12,906 & 13,469 &   797,580 &  1,052,769 \\ 
  GUANTES DE LATEX & 13,745 & 12,303 & 11,359 & 1,017,632 &    834,462 \\ 
  LIMPIADORES Y DESENGRASANTES N &  6,893 & 10,171 &  7,555 &   532,131 &    645,236 \\ 
  SUAVIZANTES &  5,725 &  9,575 &  7,670 &   572,759 &    640,669 \\ 
  LAVANDINAS &  5,694 &  7,353 &  7,360 &   464,882 &    602,875 \\ 
  CERAS PARA PISOS &  4,613 &  4,501 &  4,444 &   364,140 &    382,369 \\ 
  LUSTRAMUEBLES &  7,141 &  3,614 &  5,788 &   492,708 &    365,615 \\ 
  VIDRIOS Y MULTIUSO &  3,271 &  3,911 &  3,768 &   271,616 &    302,953 \\ 
  PRODUCTOS P/EL LAVADO FINO &  2,904 &  2,926 &  3,572 &   117,832 &    289,474 \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES EN PANES &  2,891 &  3,380 &  3,656 &   193,319 &    283,411 \\ 
  FIBRAS LIMPIADORAS &  3,406 &  3,342 &  3,295 &   231,409 &    233,841 \\ 
  LANAS/ESPONJAS Y TRAPOS METALI &  2,230 &  2,715 &  2,814 &   145,893 &    210,034 \\ 
  COCINA Y ANTIGRASA &  1,973 &  3,175 &  4,267 &   121,913 &    205,040 \\ 
  QUITAMANCHAS &  2,121 &  2,416 &  2,449 &   140,739 &    135,342 \\ 
  PA-OS SINTETICOS &  1,826 &  2,861 &  2,762 &   145,271 &    128,108 \\ 
  APRESTOS &    947 &    873 &  1,114 &    67,115 &     95,356 \\ 
  INODOROS &    874 &    798 &  1,216 &     9,834 &     51,266 \\ 
  SERVILLETAS DE PAPEL &    856 &     33 &    884 &   105,955 &     45,377 \\ 
  DESTAPACA-ERIAS &    252 &    140 &    420 &    15,798 &     10,260 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  LIMPIEZA} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
INSECTICIDAS TOTAL &   177.58 &  50.38 &  28.99 \\ 
  DESODORIZ. AMBIENTALES &   \textcolor{red}{-13.23} & \textcolor{red}{-24.01} & \textcolor{red}{-22.71} \\ 
  PAPEL HIGIENICO &    28.18 &   5.51 & \textcolor{red}{-14.72} \\ 
  DETERGENTES LIQUIDOS &    \textcolor{red}{-1.83} &  16.97 &  26.67 \\ 
  ROLLOS DE PAPEL P/COCINA &     6.99 & \textcolor{red}{-17.96} & \textcolor{red}{-13.06} \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES EN POLVO &     0.02 &  15.10 &  33.67 \\ 
  DESOD.PARA INODOROS &     3.35 & \textcolor{red}{-14.76} &  \textcolor{red}{-4.36} \\ 
  DILUIBLES &     4.36 &  21.65 &  32.00 \\ 
  GUANTES DE LATEX &    \textcolor{red}{-7.67} & \textcolor{red}{-17.36} & \textcolor{red}{-18.00} \\ 
  LIMPIADORES Y DESENGRASANTES N &   \textcolor{red}{-25.72} &   9.61 &  21.26 \\ 
  SUAVIZANTES &   \textcolor{red}{-19.90} &  33.97 &  11.86 \\ 
  LAVANDINAS &     0.09 &  29.27 &  29.68 \\ 
  CERAS PARA PISOS &    \textcolor{red}{-1.27} &  \textcolor{red}{-3.67} &   5.01 \\ 
  LUSTRAMUEBLES &    60.15 & \textcolor{red}{-18.95} & \textcolor{red}{-25.79} \\ 
  VIDRIOS Y MULTIUSO &    \textcolor{red}{-3.66} &  15.19 &  11.54 \\ 
  PRODUCTOS P/EL LAVADO FINO &    22.07 &  23.01 & 145.67 \\ 
  JABONES Y DETERGENTES EN PANES &     8.17 &  26.44 &  46.60 \\ 
  FIBRAS LIMPIADORAS &    \textcolor{red}{-1.40} &  \textcolor{red}{-3.26} &   1.05 \\ 
  LANAS/ESPONJAS Y TRAPOS METALI &     3.66 &  26.18 &  43.96 \\ 
  COCINA Y ANTIGRASA &    34.39 & 116.24 &  68.19 \\ 
  QUITAMANCHAS &     1.37 &  15.50 &  \textcolor{red}{-3.84} \\ 
  PA-OS SINTETICOS &    \textcolor{red}{-3.46} &  51.30 & \textcolor{red}{-11.82} \\ 
  APRESTOS &    27.48 &  17.56 &  42.08 \\ 
  INODOROS &    52.38 &  39.05 & 421.32 \\ 
  SERVILLETAS DE PAPEL & 2,578.79 &   3.22 & \textcolor{red}{-57.17} \\ 
  DESTAPACA-ERIAS &   200.00 &  66.69 & \textcolor{red}{-35.06} \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Valores Absolutos-Categorias de  OTC} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & Septiembre14 & Agosto15 & Septiembre15 & YTD14 & YTD15 \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
\endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
ANTISEPTICOS & 0 & 0 & 24,176 & 0 & 108,372 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|r|r|r|}
\caption{Variaciones-Categorias de  OTC} \\ 
  \hline
CATEGORY & varMA & varMMAA & varYTD \\ 
  \hline 
 \endhead 
 \hline 
 {\footnotesize Continued on next page} 
 \endfoot 
 \endlastfoot 
 \hline
ANTISEPTICOS & Inf & Inf & Inf \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Impossible to debug unconnected fragments, please make a small self contained document that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The problem is that most of the code is data wrangling to create the tables, which is irrelevant, but needed if the problem must be reproducible.
The only other chunk of code that may be of interest is the loop which calls for rmarkdown to run the .Rmd i showed in the description.
The fragments are connected, given that the result of 
    cat(xt, sep="\n")
Is the LaTex longtable i showed there.

Comment: They don't let us reproduce the problem. We need something we can copy-paste-compile to see the issue. What you've provided doesn't let us do that. So you could get lucky. But given that the author of **longtable** can't tell from the fragments you've given, you might want to think about relying on more than luck if you actually need a solution. (Rather than merely being curious, say, or intrigued by the intellectual challenge.)

Comment: See [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for help creating a suitable example.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say this has nothing to do with **longtable** and everything to do with misuse of **fancyhdr**. ***Read the console output.*** If my guess is correct, it tells you precisely what you need to do.  (If my guess is not correct, it is irrelevant, of course.)

Comment: You mean the new `longtable.sty`? Do you mean the files `longtable.ins` and `longtable.dtx` that you can access if you click on the `v5` link in @DavidCarlisle's comment? Download the files, run `latex` or `pdflatex` on them to create `longtable.sty` and `longtable.dvi`/`longtable.pdf` respectively.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I certainly hope you don't need them..! (But the OP's comment made me think he or she didn't know what `.ins` [or `.dtx`] files were/did.)

Comment: @jon ah sorry I misread the thread:-) (deleted previous comment)

Comment: I already updated with a working example of the tex file that generates the problem. I hope it helps, any other information or change you need please tell me and i will try to get it.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, ***read the console output***. It tells you precisely what the problem is and precisely what to do about it.

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 60.50554pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Setting the `headheight=61pt` in `geometry`'s options solves the problem. Note, however, that you have inconsistent and bizarre layout options scattered throughout the preamble, which is a recipe for trouble and confusion.

If combined, you end up with something like this

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=61pt,layout=a4paper,top=0.1cm,headsep=0pt]{geometry}
```

So you are setting all margins to 1" and then resetting the top one to 1mm. You are also setting the layout to A4 and the paper size to US letter. While it is possible that you really do need this configuration, it does seem rather unlikely.

Adding `showframe`, for example, we get this

[image: ugly output]

Note that the whole point of **longtable** is that it does the breaking for you. If you are going to break up the table yourself, you might just as soon use `tabular`s. Keep starting and stopping the `longtable` environment will lead to inconsistent formatting and spacing.