# Pagebreak doesn't work with floats and longtabu

Tags: floats, page-breaking, longtabu

*I'm using LuaTex.* If i have a `figure` and a `longtabu` on one page, the text after it just doesn't break.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \vspace{10cm}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{longtabu} {XX}
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} \\ 
    \end{longtabu}

    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

**How to make the text break correct?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Figure or longtabu/longtable causes bottom margin overflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213911/figure-or-longtabu-longtable-causes-bottom-margin-overflow)

Answer (score 4):

Okay i found out what's the problem.

Source: [LaTeX bugs database - single-page longtable below float clobbers \pagegoal](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512)

The problem seems to be the following:

> The longtable environment resets `\pagegoal` to `\vsize` at the end.  This
>   behavior is wrong if a document contains a float followed by a longtable
>   and both the float and the longtable fits on the same page.  In such a
>   situation, that page would become overfull by exactly the amount taken
>   up by the float, because LaTeX essentially forgets that it has decided
>   to place the float on that page.

I made the sugested changes to the `longtable.sty` file and now it works correct.

Here the complete `longtable.sty` file with all changes, that i placed in my document folder:

```
%%
%% This is file `longtable.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% longtable.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% The source is maintained by the LaTeX Project team and bug
%% reports for it can be opened at http://latex-project.org/bugs.html
%% (but please observe conditions on bug reports sent to that address!)
%% 
%% Copyright 1993-2016
%% The LaTeX3 Project and any individual authors listed elsewhere
%% in this file.
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the Standard LaTeX `Tools Bundle'.
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of the LaTeX
%% `Tools Bundle'. You may however distribute the LaTeX `Tools Bundle'
%% without such generated files.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the LaTeX `Tools Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 
%% File: longtable.dtx Copyright (C) 1990-2001 David Carlisle
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{longtable}
          [2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)]
\def\LT@err{\PackageError{longtable}}
\def\LT@warn{\PackageWarning{longtable}}
\def\LT@final@warn{%
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \LT@warn{Table \@width s have changed. Rerun LaTeX.\@gobbletwo}}%
  \global\let\LT@final@warn\relax}
\DeclareOption{errorshow}{%
  \def\LT@warn{\PackageInfo{longtable}}}
\DeclareOption{pausing}{%
  \def\LT@warn#1{%
    \LT@err{#1}{This is not really an error}}}
\DeclareOption{set}{}
\DeclareOption{final}{}
\ProcessOptions
\newskip\LTleft       \LTleft=\fill
\newskip\LTright      \LTright=\fill
\newskip\LTpre        \LTpre=\bigskipamount
\newskip\LTpost       \LTpost=\bigskipamount
\newcount\LTchunksize \LTchunksize=20
\let\c@LTchunksize\LTchunksize
\newdimen\LTcapwidth  \LTcapwidth=4in
\newbox\LT@head
\newbox\LT@firsthead
\newbox\LT@foot
\newbox\LT@lastfoot
\newcount\LT@cols
\newcount\LT@rows
\newcounter{LT@tables}
\newcounter{LT@chunks}[LT@tables]
\ifx\c@table\undefined
  \newcounter{table}
  \def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\fi
\ifx\tablename\undefined
  \def\tablename{Table}
\fi
\newtoks\LT@p@ftn
\mathchardef\LT@end@pen=30000
\def\longtable{%
  \par
  \ifx\multicols\@undefined
  \else
     \ifnum\col@number>\@ne
       \@twocolumntrue
     \fi
  \fi
  \if@twocolumn
    \LT@err{longtable not in 1-column mode}\@ehc
  \fi
  \begingroup
  \@ifnextchar[\LT@array{\LT@array[x]}}
\def\LT@array[#1]#2{%
  \refstepcounter{table}\stepcounter{LT@tables}%
  \if l#1%
    \LTleft\z@ \LTright\fill
  \else\if r#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\z@
  \else\if c#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\fill
  \fi\fi\fi
  \let\LT@mcol\multicolumn
  \let\LT@@tabarray\@tabarray
  \let\LT@@hl\hline
  \def\@tabarray{%
    \let\hline\LT@@hl
    \LT@@tabarray}%
  \let\\\LT@tabularcr\let\tabularnewline\\%
  \def\newpage{\noalign{\break}}%
  \def\pagebreak{\noalign{\ifnum`}=0\fi\@testopt{\LT@no@pgbk-}4}%
  \def\nopagebreak{\noalign{\ifnum`}=0\fi\@testopt\LT@no@pgbk4}%
  \let\hline\LT@hline \let\kill\LT@kill\let\caption\LT@caption
  \@tempdima\ht\strutbox
  \let\@endpbox\LT@endpbox
  \ifx\extrarowheight\@undefined
    \let\@acol\@tabacol
    \let\@classz\@tabclassz \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv
    \def\@startpbox{\vtop\LT@startpbox}%
    \let\@@startpbox\@startpbox
    \let\@@endpbox\@endpbox
    \let\LT@LL@FM@cr\@tabularcr
  \else
    \advance\@tempdima\extrarowheight
    \col@sep\tabcolsep
    \let\@startpbox\LT@startpbox\let\LT@LL@FM@cr\@arraycr
  \fi
  \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{\vrule
    \@height \arraystretch \@tempdima
    \@depth \arraystretch \dp \strutbox
    \@width \z@}%
  \let\@sharp##\let\protect\relax
   \begingroup
    \@mkpream{#2}%
    \xdef\LT@bchunk{%
       \global\advance\c@LT@chunks\@ne
       \global\LT@rows\z@\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup
       \LT@setprevdepth
       \tabskip\LTleft \noexpand\halign to\hsize\bgroup
      \tabskip\z@ \@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\LTright \cr}%
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\LT@nofcols\LT@bchunk&\LT@nofcols
  \LT@make@row
  \m@th\let\par\@empty
  \everycr{}\lineskip\z@\baselineskip\z@
  \LT@bchunk}
\def\LT@no@pgbk#1[#2]{\penalty #1\@getpen{#2}\ifnum`{=0\fi}}
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@\vskip\LTpre
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\LT@foot
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
    \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
    \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
        \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
        \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@foot\else
    \global\advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}}
\def\endlongtable{%
  \crcr
  \noalign{%
    \let\LT@entry\LT@entry@chop
    \xdef\LT@save@row{\LT@save@row}}%
  \LT@echunk
  \LT@start
  \unvbox\z@
  \LT@get@widths
  \if@filesw
    {\let\LT@entry\LT@entry@write\immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \gdef\expandafter\noexpand
        \csname LT@\romannumeral\c@LT@tables\endcsname
          {\LT@save@row}}}%
  \fi
  \ifx\LT@save@row\LT@@save@row
  \else
    \LT@warn{Column \@width s have changed\MessageBreak
             in table \thetable}%
    \LT@final@warn
  \fi
  \endgraf\penalty -\LT@end@pen
  \ifvoid\LT@foot\else
    \global\advance\vsize\ht\LT@foot
    \global\advance\@colroom\ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \global\@mparbottom\z@
  \endgraf\penalty\z@\addvspace\LTpost
  \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{}\fi}
\def\LT@nofcols#1&{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\LT@n@fcols}
\def\LT@n@fcols{%
  \advance\LT@cols\@ne
  \ifx\@let@token\LT@nofcols
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\LT@nofcols
  \fi}
\def\LT@tabularcr{%
  \relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@ifstar
    {\def\crcr{\LT@crcr\noalign{\nobreak}}\let\cr\crcr
     \LT@t@bularcr}%
    {\LT@t@bularcr}}
\let\LT@crcr\crcr
\let\LT@setprevdepth\relax
\def\LT@t@bularcr{%
  \global\advance\LT@rows\@ne
  \ifnum\LT@rows=\LTchunksize
    \gdef\LT@setprevdepth{%
      \prevdepth\z@\global
      \global\let\LT@setprevdepth\relax}%
    \expandafter\LT@xtabularcr
  \else
    \ifnum0=`{}\fi
    \expandafter\LT@LL@FM@cr
  \fi}
\def\LT@xtabularcr{%
  \@ifnextchar[\LT@argtabularcr\LT@ntabularcr}
\def\LT@ntabularcr{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi
  \LT@echunk
  \LT@start
  \unvbox\z@
  \LT@get@widths
  \LT@bchunk}
\def\LT@argtabularcr[#1]{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi
  \ifdim #1>\z@
    \unskip\@xargarraycr{#1}%
  \else
    \@yargarraycr{#1}%
  \fi
  \LT@echunk
  \LT@start
  \unvbox\z@
  \LT@get@widths
  \LT@bchunk}
\def\LT@echunk{%
  \crcr\LT@save@row\cr\egroup
  \global\setbox\@ne\lastbox
    \unskip
  \egroup}
\def\LT@entry#1#2{%
  \ifhmode\@firstofone{&}\fi\omit
  \ifnum#1=\c@LT@chunks
  \else
    \kern#2\relax
  \fi}
\def\LT@entry@chop#1#2{%
  \noexpand\LT@entry
    {\ifnum#1>\c@LT@chunks
       1}{0pt%
     \else
       #1}{#2%
     \fi}}
\def\LT@entry@write{%
  \noexpand\LT@entry^^J%
  \@spaces}
\def\LT@kill{%
  \LT@echunk
  \LT@get@widths
  \expandafter\LT@rebox\LT@bchunk}
\def\LT@rebox#1\bgroup{%
  #1\bgroup
  \unvbox\z@
  \unskip
  \setbox\z@\lastbox}
\def\LT@blank@row{%
  \xdef\LT@save@row{\expandafter\LT@build@blank
    \romannumeral\number\LT@cols 001 }}
\def\LT@build@blank#1{%
  \if#1m%
    \noexpand\LT@entry{1}{0pt}%
    \expandafter\LT@build@blank
  \fi}
\def\LT@make@row{%
  \global\expandafter\let\expandafter\LT@save@row
    \csname LT@\romannumeral\c@LT@tables\endcsname
  \ifx\LT@save@row\relax
    \LT@blank@row
  \else
    {\let\LT@entry\or
     \if!%
         \ifcase\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\LT@cols
         \expandafter\@gobble\LT@save@row
         \or
         \else
           \relax
         \fi
        !%
     \else
       \aftergroup\LT@blank@row
     \fi}%
  \fi}
\let\setlongtables\relax
\def\LT@get@widths{%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{%
    \unhbox\@ne
    \let\LT@old@row\LT@save@row
    \global\let\LT@save@row\@empty
    \count@\LT@cols
    \loop
      \unskip
      \setbox\tw@\lastbox
    \ifhbox\tw@
      \LT@def@row
      \advance\count@\m@ne
    \repeat}%
  \ifx\LT@@save@row\@undefined
    \let\LT@@save@row\LT@save@row
  \fi}
\def\LT@def@row{%
  \let\LT@entry\or
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \ifcase\expandafter\count@\LT@old@row
    \else
      {1}{0pt}%
    \fi}%
  \let\LT@entry\relax
  \xdef\LT@save@row{%
    \LT@entry
    \expandafter\LT@max@sel\@tempa
    \LT@save@row}}
\def\LT@max@sel#1#2{%
  {\ifdim#2=\wd\tw@
     #1%
   \else
     \number\c@LT@chunks
   \fi}%
  {\the\wd\tw@}}
\def\LT@hline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \penalty\@M
    \futurelet\@let@token\LT@@hline}
\def\LT@@hline{%
  \ifx\@let@token\hline
    \global\let\@gtempa\@gobble
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty-\@medpenalty\vskip\doublerulesep}%
  \else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@empty
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty-\@lowpenalty\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}%
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
  \noalign{\LT@sep}%
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
  \noalign{\penalty\@M}%
  \@gtempa}
\def\LT@caption{%
  \noalign\bgroup
    \@ifnextchar[{\egroup\LT@c@ption\@firstofone}\LT@capti@n}
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\def\LT@capti@n{%
  \@ifstar
    {\egroup\LT@c@ption\@gobble[]}%
    {\egroup\@xdblarg{\LT@c@ption\@firstofone}}}
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1{#2: }#3}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
      #1{#2: }#3%
    \else
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \hss}}}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@\ht\LT@foot
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
            \global\vsize\@colroom
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \unvbox\z@\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\copy\LT@foot\else\box\LT@lastfoot\fi
    \fi
  \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi}
\def\LT@end@hd@ft#1{%
  \LT@echunk
  \ifx\LT@start\endgraf
    \LT@err
     {Longtable head or foot not at start of table}%
     {Increase LTchunksize}%
  \fi
  \setbox#1\box\z@
  \LT@get@widths
  \LT@bchunk}
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}
\def\LT@startpbox#1{%
  \bgroup
    \let\@footnotetext\LT@p@ftntext
    \setlength\hsize{#1}%
    \@arrayparboxrestore
    \vrule \@height \ht\@arstrutbox \@width \z@}
\def\LT@endpbox{%
  \@finalstrut\@arstrutbox
  \egroup
  \the\LT@p@ftn
  \global\LT@p@ftn{}%
  \hfil}
\def\LT@p@ftntext#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\LT@p@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]}%
  \global\LT@p@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `longtable.sty'.
```

You can copy everything, create a `longtable.sty` file in your document folder and paste everything. Save, and you should be ready to go.