# Pagebreak doesn't work with floats and ltablex

Tags: longtable, tabularx, ltablex

I have the same problem as described here:
[Pagebreak doesn't work with floats and longtabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324227/pagebreak-doesnt-work-with-floats-and-longtabu)

I tried the provided solution approach - but it does not work. I have created a new longtable.sty and copied it in the miktex install dir, replacing the old one, but it still does not work.

any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: In my case i got first the table and then the figure (float)...sorry for that. I found a way to work around it by not putting the table in a \begin{table}...\end{table} environment but started right away with \begin{tabularx}...table now looks slightly different and it is not a nice solution but I unfortunately do not have time for more try and error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should never replace any files in the TeX distro installation. That said it would be better if you could specify what "does not work" is and post a MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Same MWE applies from the linked topic. Problem: i apply his solution approach but i do not know where to place the edited longtable.sty file. in short, i apparently do not know how to patch a .sty file

Comment: Just do what is written in the answer: Copy the posted code into a file `longtable.sty` in the same directory as your TeX is.

Comment: if by "TeX" you are referring to the directory where my tex-project is, that i am working on - i did exactly that...but it did not help.

Comment: Please check the log file if the correct longtable file is loaded, otherwise you have not put it at the right location. If the log shows the right file then the fix is not working anymore and you should update your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I checked the log. it is difficult to tell which longtable.sty is loaded as it is loaded via ltablex.sty (same as related topic)... i do not know where ltablex.sty is loading the longtable.sty from as it is not specified in the log --- it says longtable 2014/10/28 v.4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)

Comment: A typical log will tell you the path to the .sty file. And you can easily test this by changing the date of the copied file to something you will recognize...

Comment: thank you! did exactly that and it uses the modified longtable.sty from the .tex directory... seems like the patch is not working for me

Comment: Then please edit your question with that new information.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem described in the linked question, but I cannot reproduce it if I substitute the `longtable.sty` in the answer. The fix there works for me with both LuaTeX and pdfTeX. If it does not work for you, we need an MWE. Are you testing ***exactly the code*** in the linked question? That is, if you paste that code into a clean `.tex` in a clean directory and paste the new `longtable.sty` into a clean file in the same directory, you still see the problem? If so, post the log. If not, we need an MWE.

Comment: I am really sorry! just realized that in my case I have first the table and then the figure - so the other way around. I did not realize that, neither that it makes a difference... sorry. i will close this question and maybe open a new one.. THANKS for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP' edit stated the problem solved (and not clear what the original problem was)