# caption and longtable forcing text out of margin

Tags: captions, margins, longtable

Consider this example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Another caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{longtable}{rrc}
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
        A & B & C\\
\end{longtable}
%% \begin{table}                                                                                                                                                                                            
%% \begin{tabular}{rrc}                                                                                                                                                                                     
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%%         A & B & C\\                                                                                                                                                                                      
%% \end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                            
%% \end{table}                                                                                                                                                                                              
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

In the output at the end of document text is forced out of margin, as seen by the text being forced onto the page number:

[image]

Curiously, the problem disappears if a `tabular` is used in place of `longtable` or if I comment out the captions of the figures.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: @Bernard, yes I compiled twice

Comment: And if, instead of `\lipsum[1]`, you type a real text (I mean something not obtained with a command)?

Comment: @Bernard, the problem originally is from a real text wherefrom I constructed the MWE

Comment: A real plain text, not incorporating displayed  equations  and things like that?

Comment: @Bernard, the real text is with citations, newcommands and some equations. I can reproduce the problem after replacing lipsum with plain text (no equations, etc, only the figures).